# Erro com Bean e @Autowired usando Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou fazendo um programa para lojas de aluguel de trajes e estou usando Spring Boot.Os meus erros são no controller e no dao.

Segue o código do controller necessário:

```
@Controller
public class AluguelController extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private ClienteDao dao;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private AluguelRepository aluguelRepository;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private ClienteRepository clienteRepository;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private RoupaUtensiliosRepository roupaUtensiliosRepository;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private TipoRoupaRepository tipoRoupaRepository;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private RoupaUtensiliosDao rdao;
```

Segue o código do dao necessário:

```
public interface ClienteDao {

    List<Cliente> getByNomeCli(String nomeCli);
}
```

Erro mostrado pelo intellij:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field dao in com.vitoria.trajes.controller.AluguelController required a bean of type 'com.vitoria.dao.ClienteDao' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.vitoria.dao.ClienteDao' in your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Nas configurações do projeto, você precisa definir que a sua classe `ClienteDao` é um Bean, precisa definir que o pacote onde ela está seja varrido para que o spring a encontre e entenda que é um bean.

Comment: Fiz isso e continua com o mesmo erro.

Answer (score -1):

Para o bean ser criado a interface tem que ser implementada em uma classe concreta, e nesta classe ter o @Repository ou @Component no caso de um DAO.